# How do I add functionality to a winforms program in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, button

I'm trying to make a winforms version of a program [I originally wrote as a console app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368028/how-do-i-prevent-crashing-due-to-invalid-input-in-c)

Here's a [picture](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/7867/calculatorpreview.png) of my current progress. I've made the text boxes and buttons (with a read-only textbox for output). I don't know how to actually make the buttons function.

I want it to work the same as the console version did (ask for input w/ error messages for anything that isn't an positive integer, and calculate the output), but I've never done winforms before so I'm at a roadblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just double click the button and it will take you to the code behind page.
You can do something as simple as add a textbox (TextBox1) add a button (Button1)

Double click button on your winform and it will take you to the click event of the button.

In the code behind type this:

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hello World!";
```

Now run your app and click the button.

Comment: This worked. Do variables and strings work differently in a winform program as well?

Comment: They are still variables and strings, so in that sense no a string is a string is a string is a string...:).  Variables are still valid in winforms or console apps.  int c; in a console app can be int c; in a winform app can be int c; in an asp.net web app.  My recommendation is get a simple win form book.  But as long as you know how to program through the console, you can take that knowledge to the next level (win forms / web apps).  Then you need to pickup a book on events, UI, etc.

Comment: I have to say, after seeing this, everything is starting to click. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem at all.  If you have further questions or issues just post back.  But like I said , you seem like you know what you are doing and you've done some code on a console app.  It works pretty much the same as client apps (winform) or web apps.  Although, once you get involved (especially with web apps) it gets a bit more involved.  But the basics apply to all of them.

Answer (score 4):

As a beginner to WinForms, you would benefit greatly from reading up on the subject. For example:

- [Windows-Forms-Programming-Chris-Sells (Amazon.com)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321116208)